# Attach spotlights to robot links in Gazebo 1.9 + ROS Hydro?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Is it possible to do anything like attach a light to robot and then have it move around with the robot?

```
<gazebo reference="chassis">
  <light type="spot" name="front_spot">
    <pose>1 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
    <diffuse>0 1 0 1</diffuse>
    <attenuation>
      <range>10</range>
      <constant>0.2</constant>
      <linear>0.01</linear>
    </attenuation>
    <direction>1 0 0</direction>
  </light>
</gazebo>
```

(this is what I tried adding to my ros urdf file but I get this error I believe when the conversion to sdf is happening:

```
Error [parser.cc:697] XML Element[light], child of element[link] not defined in SDF. Ignoring.[link]
```

---

Update - one thing I've tried is use a texture projector, with a spotlight that fades from white to 100% transparent at the edges.  This doesn't work because the projected texture looks to be purely additive, it'll produce a spot but not reveal the texture in the model it is being projected on.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4759/attach-spotlights-to-robot-links-in-gazebo-1.9-+-ros-hydro?/) by [Lucas Walter](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/531/lucas-walter/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 115 on 2013-10-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This feature is currently not present. Here is an [issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/900/allow-attachment-of-lights-to-links) to help track its development.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1